# Delete method in Angular is not deleting

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, http-delete

I am trying to do a really basic CRUD in my first Angular application and I am having issues with the Delete method. There are no errors, the `id` parameter is passed correctly throughout the application (checked in the console), but the item is not being deleted. Basically nothing happens.

The "database" is a file named `notes.json` inside the `assets` folder of my application. It contains multiple notes like this:

```
[
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "title": "First note",
      "description": "This is the description for the first note",
      "categoryId": "1"
    }
]
```

These notes are put in the UI in the **note.component.html** in `mat-cards`.

```
<div *ngFor="let note of notes">
  <mat-card class="note">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>
        {{ note.title }}
      </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>
        {{ note.description }}
      </p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <button><mat-icon (click)="deleteNote(note.id)">delete</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Then, in **note.component.ts**, the `deleteNote` method is called. As I said above, the `note.id` parameter is passed correctly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-note',
  templateUrl: './note.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./note.component.scss'],
})
export class NoteComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() selectedCategoryId: string;
  notes: Note[];

  constructor(private noteService: NoteService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.noteService.getNotes().subscribe((result) => this.notes = result);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.selectedCategoryId) {
      this.noteService.getFilteredNotes(this.selectedCategoryId).subscribe((result) => this.notes = result);
    }
  }

  deleteNote(id:string){
    console.log(id);
    this.noteService.deleteNote(id).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});
  }
}

export interface Note {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  categoryId: string;
}
```

The service is, therefore called and performs the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class NoteService {

  readonly baseUrl = "https://localhost:4200";
  readonly httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
  };
  deleteNote(id:string)
  {
    return this.httpClient.delete(this.baseUrl + "/notes/" + id, this.httpOptions).subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
  }

}
```

Therefore, what is going wrong? My gut feeling tells me that I am using the `subscribe` method wrong, but I tried doing it differently and still getting the same result.

Comment: it can be that the item is properly deleted but the template does not render those changes. please share with us your html template and your component code. Also what get's printed in the console.log(data) ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have edited the post. Now that I am thinking of it... Could it be because if the `ngOnInit`? Also, `console.log(data)` returns null. `console.log(id)`, however, returns the correct id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that you send the request to remove that note from the backend, however in the frontend your list is never updated.

```
deleteNote(id:string){
    console.log(id);

    let indexToBeRemoved = this.notes.findIndex( (note) => {note.id === id});
   
    if (indexToBeRemoved != -1){
    this.notes.splice(indexToBeRemoved, 1);
    }
    
    this.noteService.deleteNote(id).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});
  }
}
```

If you want to be 100% safe, check the response from the backend that shows the delete was successful and then proceed with removing the element from the frontend

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a lot for your help. I have a question, though... Would there be any way that this method could be a one-liner, instead? Maybe not with the code I wrote, but I suppose that there are shorter alternatives too. At least that's what I saw in some of my colleague's code - their methods didn't seem so "complicated". So should I do something differently next time?

Comment: if the delete method from the backend returns as a result all the remaining objects then you can easily just make this.notes = data and you could reflect those changes. Don't find it good though

Comment: updated to be more elegant with less lines of code

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.